# why ! + [] = 'true', I can't test '!' in any way

Tags: javascript

I want to know the logic of the following operators

```
let test = ! + [];
console.log(test); //true
```

Why?
I can't test `!` in any way

```
typeof ! //ERROR

! && true //ERROR
```

Comment: I think it's similar with `!( +[] )`

Answer (score 9):

`!` is an operator like `+`.
If you're going to do `typeof +` you'll get the same error.

Operators can't be used like that.

The reason why `let test = ! + [];` worked is because of the order of operation ([operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)), and it determined the following order:

1. evaluate `[]`;
2. convert it to a number with `+[] //0`;
3. negate that conversion with `!0 //true`.

So, in expr `!+[]`, `+[]` was executed first, that is why Quentin pointed to that dupe

Read more about [expressions and operators on JS MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)